# Botón de cierre en la cabecera de un Panel, usando ModalPopUpExtender

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp

Estimados un cordial saludo,

alguien conoce la forma de agregar en una etiqueta: "panel" un botón de cerrar, en la parte superior derecha; **y agregarle la funcionalidad de cerrar, con jquery**; teniendo en cuenta que para mostrar el "panel" como un modal, he utilizado el extensor: modalPopUpExtender de ASP.NET

Muchas gracias por sus comentarios.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Estimados compañeros,

encontré una solución a la pregunta que he planteado y consiste en:

**Código CSS** (En la misma página que el código ASPX)

```
   <style>
   .cabeceraModal {
              display:inline-block;
                
            }
           
    .cabeceraModal #btnCerrarModal{
              position:relative;
              right : -180px;
                
            }
  </style>
```

**Código JavaScript**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
      function cerrarModal()
      {
         $("[id*='mpeVerIntegComis']").css("display", "none");
         $("#panelDatos").css("display", "none");
           
            return false;          
      }
 </script>
```

**Código ASPX**

```
  <asp:panel id ="panelDatos" runat="server" >  
         <!--cabeceraModal-->
              <div class="cabeceraModal">
                      <div class ="card-header text-center"> TÍTULO
                         <asp:button id="btnCerrarModal" runat="server" Text="X" OnClientClick="return cerrarModal();" ></asp:button>                                    
                      </div>                                 
               </div>
        <!--/cabeceraModal-->
 </asp:panel>
```

He colocado el código esencial, para la solución que he planteado. Espero pueda ser de utilidad para alguien más. Gracias.